# Gtest C++ - Can we mock the non virtual functions of same class which we are testing

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I was trying to do the unit testing in Gtest for the function BaseClass::Start. I have 2 doubts.

While doing Gtest with C++,

1.Can we mock the non virtual functions of same class which we are testing?

i.e; In my example code method IsInitialized() of the same class which I am testing.

2.Can we mock the non virtual functions of other classes which have dependency in the function we are testing?

i.e; In my example code CheckerClass::IsParamSupported(m_randomId) which is a method of the class CheckerClass

My code is given below:

```
 std::string BaseClass::Start(std::vector<int> iv) 
  {
    auto requiredIVSize = GetIvSize();

    if(!IsInitialized())
    {
        return "notInitialised";
    }
    
    if((!CheckerClass::IsParamSupported(m_randomId)) && (iv.empty() == false))
    {
        return "unsupportedParam";
    }

    if(iv.size() != requiredIVSize)
    {
        return "sizeNotCorrect";
    }
    else return "Ok";
 }
```

Comment: In standard C++ there are only tree ways to inject code: virtual method (simple), templetes (complex), function pointer or `std::function` (simple).

Comment: Also do not write test for implementation details (it looks like you are doing something like that). Write test only for functionality that public API delivers.

Comment: I need to get 100% branch coverage for the function which I am testing. That's why I need to cover all that condition checks. Do you have any idea on how to do that?

Comment: As @MarekR hinted, for non-virtual functions you can replace `CheckerClass` with a template parameter, and instantiate `BaseClass` with a mocked one. But I wonder if that would fail the 100% branch coverage requirement, because technically that generates `BaseClass` with different code. You might just have to either virtualize `CheckerClass`, or otherwise find a way to trigger every possible branch, even using system tests. If something is constant, you can try using `#ifdef` (for build flags), `if constexpr` or `std::enable_if` to remove the branch at compile time.